# Booting iMac (2011) off of external SSD

Tags: imac, ssd

I have been booting my iMac off of an external SSD.  When I initially set it up I did a clean install of high sierra and once that was booted up I used migration assistant to restore from a time machine backup.  It works well but one of the only issues that I'm noticing is that when I click on shutdown or restart the screen just goes black and the cursor stays on the screen but the system does not actually shutdown.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How long have you left it for? Did you force shutdown after this point? How many times have you tried shutting down?

Comment: Some of my older Mac do that at shutdown or reboot; takes about a minute or so of cursor or spinning black & white wheel before they finally finish. I've never fully investigated what might cause it, as it's a problem that just goes away a minute later.